# lucene support for common NLP tasks

Tags: java, lucene, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I am working on a text mining project which plans to integrate Lucene later. My current implementation uses openNLP for the common NLP tasks, such as tokenization, building n-gram features. I am curious to know that whether Lucene can support these functionalities? Does Lucene can achieve high efficiency for large scale document collections when comparing to openNLP?

Comment: Which NLP tasks? I know that Lucene does tokenization, and I believe there is a ShingleAnalyzer for doing n-grams.

Comment: The NLP tasks includes the workflow of processing document collections into feature matrix for classification/clustering purposes. They typically are consists of tokenization, generating N-gram, and constructing feature matrixes. Does Lucene provide command-line usages?

Answer (score 1):

1. Lucene provides tokenization and n-gram analysis.
2. If your Lucene documents have one or more categories, then you can implement a Hyperpipes classifier by counting the number of each category your hits fall into, then awarding the category with the most hits as the category of your query. (I'm sure there are other classifiers you could implement -- Hyperpipes just happened to come to mind as it kind of falls out of the wash from using a search engine as the backend.)
3. Since Lucene is a library, you can use it from a GUI, a command-line program, or a service (daemon).